# NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS Dynamic Number Format

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to covert an amount's decimal point to a comma. I used the query below:

```
select  tax_amt
    ,   to_char(tax_amt, '999999999999999999999999999999999999999990D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='', ''') comma
from    (
select  9.99 tax_amt from dual union all
select  99.99 tax_amt from dual union all    
select  999.99 tax_amt from dual union all
select  9999.99 tax_amt from dual union all
select  99999.99 tax_amt from dual union all
select  999999.99 tax_amt from dual union all
select  9999999.99 tax_amt from dual union all
select  99999999.99 tax_amt from dual union all
select  999999999.99 tax_amt from dual union all
select  9999999999.99 tax_amt from dual union all
select  99999999999.99 tax_amt from dual)
```

and the results seem to be correct:

```
tax_amt         zzz
--------        ----------
9.99            9,99
99.99           99,99
999.99          999,99
9999.99         9999,99
99999.99        99999,99
999999.99       999999,99
9999999.99      9999999,99
99999999.99     99999999,99
999999999.99    999999999,99
9999999999.99   9999999999,99
99999999999.99  99999999999,99
```

However, would it be possible to make the format `999999999999999999999999999999999999999990D00` dynamic?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic, can you express a little bit more please ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan i want the part "999999999999999999999999999999999999999990D00 " in the main query to be dyamic. i don't know if it will be more than 45 digits or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RPAD()` function such like

```sql
TO_NUMBER(tax_amt, 
          RPAD(REGEXP_SUBSTR(tax_amt,'[^ .]'),LENGTH(tax_amt),'9')||'0D00', 
         'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''') AS money
```

or as in your case directly by using `TO_CHAR()` conversion

```sql
TO_CHAR(tax_amt, 
        RPAD(REGEXP_SUBSTR(tax_amt,'[^ .]'),LENGTH(tax_amt),'9')||'0D00', 
       'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='', ''') AS comma
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3e566310808a703177fd66860d0f4182)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

An Oracle `number` (assuming that is what `tax_amt` is) can only have 38 digits of precision.  Practically, it seems highly unlikely that you really need to make this dynamic-- the US federal budget is a bit under $5 trillion a year.  If your `tax_amt` was enough to fund the entire US government for an entire year, it would only have 12 digits before the decimal point.  If you build a format mask with, say, 15 digits before the decimal point, that gives you space to handle the US budget for the next century or so depending on inflation.  That seems more than adequate.

Technically though, sure.  You could run a separate query to get the maximum value in the `tax_amt` column and then create a format string by `lpad`-ing "9"'s out to whatever the length of that value is.  That doesn't seem particularly worthwhile but you could do it.